# How do I get my DO droplet to listen on port 80 and port 443?

Tags: domain-name-system

I can connect to my wordpress/ubuntu droplet through Putty and DigitalOcean console, but not through any web browser to connect to wordpress login admin. The problem: tcp ports 80 and 443 are now showing closed and connection refused. DNS A record (DO gave me a new IP) also not cached around the world even after 4 days. Double checked configuration in the droplet and set droplet firewall (even though none were set in the first place), and applied sudo rules UFW in console for allowing the ports. Domain is configured correctly. Disabled my own firewall on windows. What could the problem be??

EDIT: one possible answer to this is that when I went to rebuild the snapshot for this droplet I was given a new IP address. I am told that I should not have been given a new IP address. Presumably it has either created an entirely new droplet or is corrupted.

Comment: check the webserver is already running

Comment: also add more clarity to you question, webserver version os version

Comment: I would note that this was first asked on super user, and migrated to the WordPress stack, where it then made its way here. I'm not sure if the user has an account on this specific stack though looking at the question :/